# How do I construct a JFrame child class?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

I'm trying to make a child class from `JFrame`. I think im doing it correctly but when I run this it opens a blank window without a name or background color (my `JPanel` class does the background. However, I know the error is not there because I commented out the add(`Jpanel`) and the window still didn't have a name) Also eclipse doesn't show any syntax errors.  Why doesn't this code work?:

### **Main Class:**

```
package ashwin.engine;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
public class Execute {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int[] bcolor = new int[3];
                bcolor[0] = 254;
                bcolor[1] = 0;
                bcolor[2] = 0;
                Window  wndw = new Window("Test", 1000, 1000, bcolor, true);

            } });

    }

}
```

### JFrame Child Class:

```
package ashwin.engine;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
public class Window extends JFrame {
    Window(String name, int width, int length, int[] backgroundColor, boolean visible) {

        System.out.println("made it to frame class");

        setName(name);
        setVisible(visible);
        setSize(width, length);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        Display display = new Display(backgroundColor);


    }
}
```

edit:
Forgot to mention, it does print out my debug statement "made it to frame class", dont know if that helps but I thought I should point it out.

Comment: Are you sure about setName()? If I had to guess, I would say, you mean setTitle() to set the title of the window. Setting the background should be setBackground().

Comment: @MPirious you were right. I meant setTitle. Normally I construct an object of JFrame and in the constructor I simply enter the title. I just figured that was called the "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `setName` but `setTitle`. This will effectively display the name on the screen.
For the background, you should use `getContentPane().setBackgroundColor(Color color)`

The chode should look like this:

```java
public class Execute {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Color bcolor = new Color(254, 0, 0);

                final Window wndw = new Window("Test", 1000, 1000, bcolor, true);

            }
        });

    }

}

public class Window extends JFrame {
    Window(final String name, final int width, final int length, final Color backgroundColor,
            final boolean visible) {

        System.out.println("made it to frame class");
        this.setTitle(name);
        this.setSize(width, length);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(backgroundColor);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(visible);

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, quick question: What does getContentPane() do?

Comment: @AshwinGupta Refer to the java docs - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Answer (score 2):

Make the setVisible line the last line.